# Downloaded a FTDI virtual com port driver for windows 10/11 to set up a go board for fpga learning, but I can't access the port on tera term or DM

Tags: usb, drivers, serial-port, ftdi

I tried updating drivers and changing three different cables (micro USB cable), I tried doing the same thing to my other laptop, but no luck.
I also tried going back to Windows 10, enabling hidden files, and adding legacy hardware but no luck.

After that, I uninstall the driver and reinstall it again. Checked their installation user guide.

Is it a cable problem or something else. I am looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get have a visible COM-port when you right click `This computer` and select `Manage`?
*One more step needed, can't remember what that final section to select is named*

If not; look up the driver in there, right click it and select properties, then find `[x] Load VCP` and make sure there is a tick or cross as shown here.
*VCP = Virtual COM port*

I believe this is necessary for all FTDI-based VCP:s.

*This is incomplete as I can't recollect the item names, hope it gives a hint on where to look at least*